# Set user field value in after properties

Tags: 2010

I need to set the current user in a field that is User Lookup.
I have the following code which works fine for the datetime field but not for the user.
It does not return any error, but when I try to edit the document properties again the user was not saved.

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           Logger.LogDebug("IncomingDocumentListEvents", "ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)", "BEGIN");
           string contentTypeName = properties.ListItem.ContentType.Name;
           if (contentTypeName == Subsidies.Common.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_BANKCERTIFICATE_NAME)
           {
               base.ItemUpdating(properties);
               try
               {
                   base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
                   SPItemEventDataCollection afterProperties = properties.AfterProperties;
                   SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
                    if (item != null)
                   {
                       string listName = item.ParentList.RootFolder.Name;
                       string approvedStatus = item.GetTaxonomyFieldValueByLanguage(item.Web.Site, Subsidies.Common.Constants.FIELDS_INCOMINGODOCUMENTSTATUS_NAME, 1043);

                       if (approvedStatus == Subsidies.Common.Constants.FIELDS_INCOMINGODOCUMENTAPPROVEDSTATUS_NAME)
                       {
                           SPUser user = item.Web.SiteUsers[item.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName];
                           afterProperties[Subsidies.Common.Constants.FIELDS_ACCOUNTINGAUDITORNAME_NAME] = user;
                           afterProperties.SetAfterPropertyValue(Subsidies.Common.Constants.FIELDS_APPROVALDATE_NAME, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")); 

                       }
                   }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Logger.LogError("IncomingDocumentListEvents", "ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)", ex);
                   properties.ErrorMessage = "";
                   properties.Cancel = true;
               }
               finally
               {
                   base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
               }
           }

           Logger.LogDebug("AgendaPointsProposedEvents", "ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)", "END");
       }
```

Comment: The ItemUpdating is used for validation. If you want to set the values of fields, do it in the ItemUpdated event instead.

Comment: indeed it works in the itemupdated

Comment: just put it as an answer to give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemUpdating` is used for validation. If you want to set the values of fields, do it in the `ItemUpdated` event instead...